# error al consultar en mysql desde php Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysqli

al intentar realizar un consulta en mysql desde php para iniciar una sesion me aparece el siguiente error: 
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\procesologin.php on line 10
después de la consulta tengo un if mysqli_fetch_array() y luego un else,
 siempre se me va al else, no ingresa al if, justo ahi es que sale el error.
me podrian decir como solucionarlo
este es el codigo html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>   
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Documento sin título</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form role="form" action="procesologin.php" method="POST">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" name="usuario" type="text" autofocus>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" name="contrasena" type="password" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Ingresar">
    </body>
</html>
```

esta es la conexion a la base de datos:

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "prueba";
$tabla_db1 = "usuario";
$conexion = new mysqli($server,$user,$pass,$db);
?>
```

y este es el proceso:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("conexionprueba.php");
$user = $_POST['usuario'];
$password = $_POST['contrasena'];
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE user = $user AND password = $password");
if ($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    echo "sesion exitosa";}
else{
    echo "sesion no exitosa";}
?>
```

Gracias

Comment: formatea tu código asi no se lee completo

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usarlo de manera mas facil si usas objetos segun la documentacion de php se debe hacer asi.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "world");

/* comprobar la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$consulta = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {

    /* obtener el array de objetos */
    while ($obj = $resultado->fetch_object()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $obj->Name, $obj->CountryCode);
    }

    /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
    $resultado->close();
}

/* cerrar la conexión */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```